# usage of "Made for"

Tags: meaning, grammaticality, idioms

eg. I would've made for a bad lawyer.
conveying the meaning that if I had been a lawyed, I would have been a bad one.
is it correct usage?

Answer (score 3):

One of the uses of **make** when used in this construction is *be suitable for*. Check it out in 
[OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/make).

I've never heard this expression used with the preposition **for**. The expression should be *"I would have made a bad lawyer".*

EDIT: Following Fumblefingers' and Lynn's comments, I found the phrasal verb ***make for something***, which means *help to make something possible* (from the OALD entry for **make**. The example cited is *"Constant arguing doesn't make for a happy marriage."*). I cannot find evidence that this usage can apply to human potential. I insist that "I would have made *for* a bad lawyer" isn't accepted usage.

Comment: There is 'I was never made for a lawyer', similar to the commoner *meant for*. But +1 for a helpful answer.

Comment: But OP is asking about *made **for***, not *made*. I'm quite familiar with the usage - maybe it's a BrE thing.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not clear about what you're saying. Are you saying that you find the OP's example familiar? I agree with Irene in finding it deviant.

Comment: @ColinFine - I've heard 'made for' in BrE situations (TV, etc.) but I agree in AmE you would more commonly hear 'made'.

Comment: @lynn: Interesting comment. I would have said exactly the opposite; only used in American TV shows. Perhaps it's one of the solecisms scritwriters use to indicate 'hardboiled lowlife'.

Comment: I don't recognise 'made for' at all, and I'm English.

Comment: @TimLymington - I've heard 'made for' in regards to *things* but not people.  "It wasn't made for hammering." sounds just fine.  "He wasn't made for being a lawyer." sounds weird to my ears.

Comment: @Colin Fine: Many instances of [(something) would have made **for** a (something else)](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22would+have+made+for+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) are for the sense under discussion. In some cases you could say including "for" implies that the *first* "something" was only one part of whatever would be needed to result in a "something else" (i.e. - *make **for** = contribute towards*), but often there's no such implication. If you don't recognise the form, maybe it's not particularly BrE, but it's definitely used by many speakers in at least some contexts.

Comment: ...related is the oft-repeated ["hard cases make for bad law"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22hard+cases+make+for+bad+law%22&aq=f&oq=%22hard+cases+make+for+bad+law%22&aqs=chrome.0.57.18669764j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), where there's no doubt in my mind the "for" is important - it conveys that although the hard cases don't *directly* create/become bad law, they can certainly be at least a major factor.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I must admit I wasn't familiar with the use you are describing in your comments. As Lynn says, however, I can find evidence it is used for things only, not people. I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ Irene: [if she'd been a wolf, she'd have made for a great Alpha bitch](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22she%27d+have+made+for+a%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). [Saul would have made for a much better story](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22Saul+would+have+made+for+a+much%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1). Etc., etc. It's just *more likely* with inanimate subjects, not *restricted to them*.

Comment: @Lynn: You're obviously not familiar with the usage under consideration. The way you parse it implies *someone else* (God, perhaps) didn't make him in such a way that he could be a lawyer. But I use the form myself, and I don't parse it that way. I simply see [you would make for a fine ambassador](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22you+would+make+for+a+fine+ambassador%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) as a slightly distanced/hypothetical version of the same sentiment expressed without the word **for**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I've heard the usage, I just don't see it used that way much in the US.  In my experience (which is by no means a universal rule for all of AmE), "you would make a fine ambassador" is the standard, but we *do* say "It wasn't made *for* hammering." when speaking of things.

Comment: @Lynn: What can I say? Originally you *"never heard this expression"*. Now you've *"heard the usage"*, but apparently with this arbitrary constraint that it's only used of inanimate subjects. I've just checked the context of my [fine ambassador](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22you+would+make+for+a+fine+ambassador%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) link, and I find that the author ([Thomas San Roman](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100129111622AAWVvrK)) says *I, like plenty of other people **in the USA**, have been hit fairly hard with the economic downturns of society*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Are you sure you're not mixing up my comments with someone else's?  My very first comment on this thread was that I *had* heard the expression, but mostly from British TV.  At any rate, I have posted a summary of my remarks as an answer.

Comment: @Lynn: You said *I've heard 'made for' in regards to things **but not people***. I'm just saying there's no direct connection between *"He would have made for a good lawyer"*, for example, and *"He wasn't made for being a lawyer"*. That second one sounds a bit weird to me too - but there's no doubt if we accept it at all, the word **for** must be present. OP is asking about the first form, where I seem to one of the minority who find the usage perfectly acceptable with or without **for**. But I'm not convinced this is a US/UK usage division.

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, yes, "I would have made for a bad lawyer" means that you would have been a bad lawyer if you had become one.

However, as the extended comment trail on the other answer attests, there are some regional (and perhaps personal) preferences on whether to use the word 'for' in that sense.  I see these two statements as equivalent:

> I would have *made* a bad lawyer.
>
> I would have *made for* a bad lawyer.

The first is more idiomatic to my AmE ears.  I have seen the second more commonly in BrE uses (books, TV).   But even in AmE, one commonly uses *made for* to speak of inanimate objects/concepts:

> Constant arguing doesn't make for a happy marriage.
>
> This screwdriver wasn't made for hammering.